# VBA - GoTo Command

Tags: excel, vba, goto

I'm trying to use the GoTo command in Excel to GoTo a variable cell value, but I'm struggle how to get the cell address into VBA, any thoughts?

Within my Excel document I have defined the name of a cell (i.e. created a range), lets call it "x" for ease, that contains the cell address, for example $B$3.  However it's important to note the value within the range changes as I modify the document, it's not static.

I have tried
`Application.GoTo Range("x")`
and
`Application.GoTo Range("x").value`
but neither of these seem to work.

Can I achieve what I need to using GoTo or should I be using a different command entirely?

The context should it help is that I have created a task list tab and when selecting that tab I want to GoTo the latest actionable task.  I understand what this is, I just can't reach it!

Comment: Set your named range to a variable then do `range(variable).select`.

Answer (score 0):

You set a string variable to the cell location, and then use `GoTo` with `Reference` - see example below:

```
Dim myCell As String
myCell = Range("A3").Value
Application.GoTo Reference:=Range(myCell)
```

Answer (score -1):

The GoTo statement is used for branching in the code only. It doesn't interact with the cells at all. See the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement).

As findwindow says in the comments, you need to use the Range.select method. [MSDN here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.select)

Comment: OP is using `Application.GoTo` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto